# NSURL's parameterString confusion with use of ';' vs '&'

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, url, parameters, nsurl

I'd like to use [`-[NSURL parameterString]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-BAJCFFHC) to parse out the parameters of a URL I've been passed. It says URL must conform to [RFC 1808](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1808.txt) but now wondering if ours do?!? We use something like:

`http://server/path/query?property1=value1&property2=value2`

but RFC 1808 never mentions the ampersand (**&**) as a valid parameter separator (at least the way I read it). It suggests the semicolon (**;**). Perhaps because it was drafted in 1995? Has the **&** replaced the **;**? If so anyone verify if NSURL's parameterString will also parse with & as delimiter?

What's the "right" way before we dig a big a hole?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to RFC 1808 (2.1. URL Syntactic Components) correct syntax is as follows :

```
<scheme>://<net_loc>/<path>;<params>?<query>#<fragment>
```

It says query information is formatted as per Section 3.3 of RFC 1738 which tells us :

"Within the path and searchpart components, "/", ";", "?" are reserved."

To me the above says that in your URL the path (to your CGI) is :

```
http://server/path/query
```

and the query is :

```
property1=value1&property2=value2
```

Which does not contain any reserved characters. So you are OK. In fact the use of the "&" as a separator in the query string here derives from the [CGI specification](http://hoohoo.ncsa.illinois.edu/cgi/forms.html) and not the URL RFC :

"Form data is a stream of name=value pairs separated by the & character."

Comment: very helpful...thanks! hard to **search** for this stuff on Web because every friggin' URL "hits" in one way or another.

Answer (score 2):

RFC1808 doesn't define the internal format of the query string. I believe the semicolon stuff 1808 is talking about is additional information of a different sort (on paths), which is in practice never used. 
As far as I can see, the NSURL interface does not include any methods that deal with parsing/splitting the contents of the query string itself, so this is of no interest to the class, and indeed your URL is 1808-compliant.

Actually query strings don't inherently have any RFC-defined format; you can perfectly well put any string in them and retrieve them untouched at the server side. However the HTML standard describes a way of creating query strings from form contents, and this `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format is used by most server-side scripts.

According to HTML4 section 17.13.4.1, `&` is the parameter separator browsers *must* use to create query strings from multiple parameters, so yes, you must support the ampersand as a parameter separator. HTML4 recommends that server-side scripts should *accept* the semicolon as an alternative separator to the ampersand in  query strings, as that avoids more escaping. But it doesn't require it, and indeed (unfortunately) many server/form-reading environments do not accept the semicolon for this purpose.