# How do I parse a NSString?

Tags: ios, nsstring

I have a string

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=4s-PbMuNooo
```

I want to get string 4s-PbMuNooo. How do I parse a NSString?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903157/ios-parse-a-url-into-segments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer :

```
NSString *myString = @"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=4s-PbMuNooo";
NSArray *components = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
NSString *query = [components lastObject];
```

Problems :

1) What if the bit after the q= contains another =

2) What if the q= bit is missing?

A better answer is for you to [read the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsstring_Class/Reference/NSString.html) - there are lots of helper methods on NSString that will get you substrings. Look for rangeOfString to find out where the equals would be and subStringWithRange to get the bit you want.

EDIT: Thomas has raised a fair point about URL parsing - see his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22581381/13000)

Comment: That's a sloppy solution that's a bad example for others. The URL should be first parsed into a NSURL object, then one can get the query sector from it, only THAT should then be split. See my own answer.

Comment: Hence the two problems I mention in my answer :) Nothing in the original question says it's always a _valid_ URL. Perhaps I should have included a Correct™ answer as well :| I'll just link to your answer instead!

Answer (score 2):

A slightly longer but more complete answer.  Hope this helps:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?param1=yeah&param2="];
NSArray *listItems = [[url query] componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
NSMutableDictionary *keyValues = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:listItems.count];
for (NSString *item in listItems) {
    NSArray *keyValue = [item componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
    NSAssert(keyValue.count == 2, @"Key value pair mismatch");
    [keyValues setObject:[keyValue objectAtIndex:1] forKey:[keyValue objectAtIndex:0]];
}

NSLog(@"1: %@", [keyValues objectForKey:@"param1"]);
NSLog(@"2: %@", [keyValues objectForKey:@"param2"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
NSArray *listItems = [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
NSString *myFinalString=[NSString stringWithString:[listItems objectAtIndex:1]];
```

Comment: Assuming that the bit after q= won't contain another '=' ;)

Comment: Assuming alot of things, dean.

Comment: Agreed lots of assumptions - I just thought that if the OP is asking about parsing strings, the OP won't know what assumptions have been made. (And I like that George's answer is exactly the same as ours, just 10 minutes late :)

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to try this a bit, so here is my code that handles more than one parameters:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?p=123123&q=234"];
NSArray *queryArray = [[url query] componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];

for (NSString *queryString in queryArray) {
    NSArray *queryComponents = [queryString componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
    if ([[queryComponents objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"q"]) {
        NSLog(@"Found q: %@", [queryString substringFromIndex:2]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Did not find q.");
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the url `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?p=123123&q=234=5` - your code will return '123' but the q parameter is '123=5' ;)

Comment: `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?p=123123&q=` will crash on `substringFromIndex:2` I think (index out of bounds)

Comment: No, it will just return an empty string, but it *will* crash on `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?p=123123&q` (without the = in the end). Anyway, that's enough for now!

Answer (score 1):

The question and its title are badly chosen - the answers are generally right for the more general task of splitting ANY string up, but bad for splitting up URLs as this question is actually about.

Here's how to properly get the values from a URL:

To break up a URL string, first do this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

Then retrieve the parameters (the part past the "?") like this:

```
NSString *query = [url query];
```

Now you can go ahead and split that query string up using componentsSeparatedByString:@"&" as shown in the other answers.