# Parse a url string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, parsing

I have a URL string with a url and attributes. Please provide me some logic so that I can parse the url.The URL is of the format :

`url= http://www.sample.com?`" another url here with parameters separated by &" &param

I want the "another url here with parameters separated by &" in one string and "param" in another.

I am using IOS i.e. objective c.

Thank You.

Comment: provide one full string so that i can give you clear answer.

Answer (score 4):

`NSURL` has a method `pathComponents`, which returns an array with all the different path components.

```
NSString *url_ = @"foo://name.com:8080/12345;param?foo=1&baa=2#fragment";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url_];

NSLog(@"scheme: %@", [url scheme]); 
NSLog(@"host: %@", [url host]); 
NSLog(@"port: %@", [url port]);     
NSLog(@"path: %@", [url path]);     
NSLog(@"path components: %@", [url pathComponents]);        
NSLog(@"parameterString: %@", [url parameterString]);   
NSLog(@"query: %@", [url query]);       
NSLog(@"fragment: %@", [url fragment]);
```

output:

```
scheme: foo
host: name.com
port: 8080
path: /12345
path components: (
    "/",
    12345
)
parameterString: param
query: foo=1&baa=2
fragment: fragment
```

Source: [iOS: parse a URL into segments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903157/ios-parse-a-url-into-segments)

Comment: @Varun Chaudhary, Can you please accept this if it is helpful?