# How to get an NSURL part without query string?

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

What I have:

```
http://hello.com/what?key=value&key1=value1
```

What I want:

```
http://hello.com/what
```

Now I am splitting an NSURL URL by "?" character and get its first part:

```
[NSURL URLWithString:[request.URL.absoluteString componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"][0]]
```

Is this a correct solution or there is more practical/correct one?

Comment: [url query]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903157/ios-parse-a-url-into-segments

Comment: @Wain, thank you. Should I delete this question or what?

Comment: If the other question sorts you out, yes, give it some votes and delete this one :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the answers in the linked duplicate is without issues. However, one can rely on the fact, that the first `?` from a valid URI string (from left) separates the query component from the former URI components - if any. Note, that a query *may* have additional questions marks within it. So, the simple and correct solution should be obvious. ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper, wow, I really forgot about multiple ? marks... thanks!